# Regex. Find files that last character is 'x'

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I'm trying to find file name that last character is 'x'. Here what I try to do

```
ls -l/bin[s$]
```

but this is not working. What's wrong?

Comment: Define "not working"? You need a space between `-l` and the path (or you'll get an error). Also you don't want the `$` in the `[]` and `ls` doesn't take regular expressions it takes patterns so you want `*s`.

Comment: But how I need to check if file last character is 'x' then?

Comment: Like I said `*s` matches all files that end with `s` because the `*` expands to anything followed by "s" at the end.

Answer (score 4):

ls -l /bin/*s should work, it shows all files that end in "s" at/bin/

Answer (score 0):

You can search `/dir/to/search` for all files ending in `x` like this:

```
 find /dir/to/search/ -name ".*x" -ls
```